# Where can I view rountrip information in my ASP.NET application?

Tags: asp.net, filepath, roundtrip

I'm playing around with storing application settings in my database, but I think I may have created a situation where superfluous roundtrips are being made.  Is there an easy way to view roundtrips made to an MS Access (I know, I know) backend?

I guess while I'm here, I should ask for advice on the best way to handle this project.  I'm building an app that generates links based on file names (files are numbered ints, 0-5000).  The files are stored on network shares, arranged by name, and the paths change frequently as files are bulk transfered to create space, etc.

Example:

- Files 1000 - 2000 go to /path/1000s
- Files 2001 - 3000 go to /path/2000s
- Files 3001 - 4000 go to /path/3000s

etc

I'm sure by now you can see where I'm going with this.  Ultimately, I'm trying to avoid making a roundtrip to get the paths for every single file as they are displayed in a gridview.

I'm open to the notion that I've gone about this all wrong and that my idea might be rubbish.  I've toyed around with the notion of just creating a flat file, but if I do that, do I still run into the problem of having that file opened and closed for every file displayed in a gridview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) set A breakpoint in the first line of page_load section in code by clicking in the leftmost bar (a dim thick line down the left side). You should se a round and red mark there then
2) ... and run Debug in Visual Studio (hit F5)
3) Turn back to Visual Studio after the app has started and step through the program, line-by-line, by pushing the F8 button. Great fun